# VideoViews in RecylerView have wrong size

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that has a list of ImageViews (visible) and VideoViews (hidden). If the user clicks on an ImageView, the ImageView is hidden and the VideoView made visible, also an Video is loaded from an **external source** and the video is started.

My issue: The VideoView doesn't have the correct size (its actually not visible at all). Only if I give the VideoView a fixed size, the video is shown. Here is my XML for the list-items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:background="#ffaa00">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dataImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/dataVideoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Is this a common issue with the VideoView inside a RecyclerView? Is there a workaround or do I just have to adjust my XML?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to force the alignment on the VideoView in order its fill the parent:

```
 <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/dataVideoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"       
        android:visibility="gone" />
```